# (C# WPF) How to change textrange background color?

Tags: c#, wpf, background-color, flowdocument

I am using a "flowdocumentreader" to show text, the xaml code of the "flowdocumentreader" is simple:

```
<FlowDocumentReader x:Name="myDocumentReader" ViewingMode="Scroll" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ContextMenuOpening="myDocumentReader_ContextMenuOpening" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" PreviewMouseDown="myDocumentReader_PreviewMouseDown">
    <FlowDocument x:Name="flow" LineHeight="{Binding ElementName=slider2, Path=Value}" PagePadding="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}">
        <Paragraph x:Name="paraBodyText"/>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

And I load .rtf documents to the "flowdocumentreader" like this:

```
paraBodyText.Inlines.Clear();
string temp = File.ReadAllText(dlg.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp));
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(flow.ContentStart, flow.ContentEnd);
textRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
myDocumentReader.Document = flow;
```

Now, my question is, how to get the background color of a string in the "flowdocumentreader"?

I know how to search for a string, but I don't know how to check the back ground color of such string. Is there a way to do that? I tried to get the textrange of the string and then do this:

```
TextRange selection = ....; // this is the textrange of the string
var a = selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty)
```

However, the variable "a" always returns null. :(

Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT**:
The .rtf document that I loaded into the "FlowDocumentReader" has background colors. Some are green and some are yellow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> However, the variable "a" always returns null. :(

What if you actually set a background colour?:

```
TextRange selection = new TextRange(flow.ContentStart, flow.ContentEnd);
var a = selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
a = selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
```

---

```
<FlowDocumentReader x:Name="myDocumentReader" ViewingMode="Scroll" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <FlowDocument x:Name="flow">
        <Paragraph x:Name="paraBodyText">
            some text...
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

There is no default value for the TextElement.BackgroundProperty property of a TextRange which is why you get a null reference back from the GetPropertyValue method the first time using the above sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The .rtf document that I loaded into the "FlowDocumentReader" has background colors, some are green and some are yellow. But I still got null values as I traverse through the textrange.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of this .rtf then?

Comment: Yes, of course. The .rtf document contains only one sentence as shown in my edited post. It's for testing only, and only 1KB of size. BTW, please ignore the content of the .rtf document, it "is" an rtf document. :)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Do you want this? {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Georgia;}{\f3\fcharset0 DengXian;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs21\f0\cf0 \cf0\qj{\f3 {\ltrch This }{\cf2\highlight3\ltrch is a tex}{\highlight3\ltrch t about to b}{\cf4\highlight3\ltrch e conv}{\highlight3\ltrch erted to rtf.}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\qj\par}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but finally got to discover why, the issue is that sometimes the Background property gets added to a Span that contains the text Run and we are asking for the Run background color, not its parent (the Span or the Paragraph), more information in my Question/Answer:

[C# WPF RichText Box BackgroundProperty returns null when reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831783/c-sharp-wpf-richtext-box-backgroundproperty-returns-null-when-reading-from-file/45525648#45525648)