# C# WPF RichText Box BackgroundProperty returns null when reading from file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a RichText editor, save/load file, etc.

I can assign a highlight color to the text (or a background color) using:

```
TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
selectionTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, backgroundColor);
```

background color is a Brush

This part works and I can save it to a file using:

```
filepath = savedialog.FileName;
TextRange t = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
FileStream file = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);
t.Save(file, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
```

this file can be opened on WordPad and everything works fine

now I can load the file to my program again with:

```
range = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
if (fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3).ToLower().Equals("rtf"))
{
    range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
else
{
    range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Text);
}
fStream.Close();
```

And it displays correctly with text highlight, Font, size, everything correct just as on WordPad

Here comes the issue:

but when I run

```
TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
SolidColorBrush newBrush =  (SolidColorBrush)selectionTextRange.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
```

It returns null even when the highlight is working (is visible)

the weird part is that it does returns the correct color when I assign it from within the aplication and then asks for it, but when loading a file is like if the TextRange didnt have the BackgroundProperty but every other property is there, and even weirder is that on the debugger I can analize the 
selectionTextRange variable and it has an "XML" with the correct background there just that this "XML" is not accessible in any form, ony visible from the debugger

I found other 2 similar questions but with no answer:

[(C# WPF) How to change textrange background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578080/c-wpf-how-to-change-textrange-background-color)

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iPuKFYskoNQJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595989/wpf-not-remembering-backgroundproperty-on-load-from-a-save+&cd=1&hl=es&ct=clnk&gl=co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly found what was the issue by using XAML instead of RTF I could "easily" read it as txt and understand what was happening (continue using RTF, just that with XAML I could understand what was happening), the code:

```
TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
SolidColorBrush newBrush =  (SolidColorBrush)selectionTextRange.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
```

only reads the `<Run>` properties as in `<Run Background="#FF00FF">Some Text</Run>` not the `<Span>` or the `<Paragraph>` properties as in:

```
<Paragraph Background="#00FF00"><Span><Run>Some Text</Run></Span></Paragraph>
<Paragraph Background="#00FF00"><Run>Some Text</Run></Paragraph>
<Span Background="#00FF00"><Run>Some Text</Run></Span>
<Paragraph><Span Background="#00FF00"><Run>Some Text</Run></Span></Paragraph>
```

or any other thing alike, so experimenting a little I came up with this and it's working:

```
 TextRange selectionTextRange = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
 SolidColorBrush newBrush = null;
 newBrush = (SolidColorBrush)selectionTextRange.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty);
 SolidColorBrush newBrush2 = null;
 newBrush2 = (SolidColorBrush)rtb.Selection.Start.Paragraph.Background;
 SolidColorBrush newBrush3 = null;
 try {
     newBrush3 = (SolidColorBrush)((Span)((Run)rtb.Selection.Start.Parent).Parent).Background;
 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
     //Selection Parent is Run
     //Run Parent can be Span, Paragraph, etc.
     //Parent is not Span
 }

 if (newBrush == null) {
     if (newBrush2 == null) {
         if (newBrush3 == null) {
             ClrPcker_Bg.SelectedColor = Colors.Transparent;
          }
          else {
              ClrPcker_Bg.SelectedColor = newBrush3.Color;
          }
      }
      else {
          ClrPcker_Bg.SelectedColor = newBrush2.Color;
      }
  }
  else {
      ClrPcker_Bg.SelectedColor = newBrush.Color;
  }
```

I feel the last `if` can be optimized somehow but this is working.